# How to solve integration of a product of an exponential and a trigonometric function?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Preparing for the exam I bumped into this integral and I just can't get hold on it. It's an integration of a product of an exponential and a trigonometric function. It's going in an endless loop for me.

$$ \int \cos(x)e^{2x} dx $$

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Meanwhile I solved it myself, you can find the solution in the answers below. :)

Comment: Do by parts twice and this integral will appear in an equation you can solve for.

Comment: Take the equation you get after two applications of by parts and get everything  but this integral on one side, the other side will be the answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, thank you guys a lot, I managed to solve it with your help of course. Here how it goes.

$$I = \int e^{2x}cos(x)dx$$

$ \int e^{2x}cos(x)dx = e^{2x}sinx -2\int e^{2x}sin(x)dx $

$ \int e^{2x}cos(x)dx = e^{2x}sinx -2(-e^{2x}cos(x) + 2\int e^{2x}cos(x)dx) $

$ \int e^{2x}cos(x)dx = e^{2x}sinx +2e^{2x}cos(x) -4\int e^{2x}cos(x)dx $

Since 
$$\int e^{2x}cos(x)dx=I$$

$I = e^{2x}sinx +2e^{2x}cos(x) -4I$

$5I= e^{2x}sinx +2e^{2x}cos(x)$

$I = \frac{e^{2x}sinx +2e^{2x}cos(x)}{5} $

therefore
$$ \int e^{2x}cos(x)dx=\frac{e^{2x}sinx +2e^{2x}cos(x)}{5} + C$$

Hope others like me will find it useful. :)

Comment: You asked a question, recieved many answers, then posted your own answe based on the answers you got, and accepted it. Generally, that is not good practice (you should accept the answer that helped you finish your problem, it's only fair to the user who posted it!)

Answer (score 2):

Denote $I=\int e^{2x} \cos{x} dx$ integrate by parts you get:

$$I=\left(\frac{e^{2x}\cos{x}}{2}\right)+\int\frac{e^{2x}\sin{x}}{2} dx$$

Integrate by parts a second time. We get

$$\int\frac{e^{2x}\sin{x}}{2} dx=\frac{e^{2x}\sin{x}}{4}-\int\frac{e^{2x}\cos{x}}{4} dx$$

and this combined with the above yields:

$$I=\left(\frac{e^{2x}\cos{x}}{2}\right)+\frac{e^{2x}\sin{x}}{4}-\frac{I}{4}$$

an equation in $I$ you can solve

Answer (score 2):

we will evaluate this integral by using  the fact that $e^{-2x}\int e^{2x}\cos x \, dx$ is a particular solution of the differential equation $$y' + 2y = \cos x.\tag 1$$ you can find a particular solution of $(1)$ by looking for $y = A\cos x + B \sin x.$ subbing in $(1),$  we get $$-A\sin x + B \cos x+2(A\cos x + B \sin x)=\cos x \to 2B - A = 0, 2A + B= 1. $$ that gives you $$ B = \frac 15, A = \frac 25, e^{-2x}\int e^{2x}\cos x = \frac 25 \cos x + \frac 15 \sin x$$ that is $$\int e^{2x}\cos x\, dx = e^{2x} \left(\frac 25 \cos x + \frac 15 \sin x \right) + C$$

Comment: Thanks man, but as you can see I already solved it, myself, and the solution is like yours. :D +1 for +1 xD

Comment: @sectumsempra, you are welcome bro.

Answer (score 0):

After repeated integration by parts.. you get the following equation:

$$\int \cos(x)e^{2x}dx=e^{2x}\sin(x)-2(2\int \cos(x)e^{2x}dx-e^{2x}\cos(x))$$

Solve for the integral, to get your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that $e^{2x}$ is multiplied by a constant when integrated or differentiated; the same for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, with the added “problem” that they're also interchanged with one another. So you can look for
$$
F(x)=ae^{2x}\cos x+be^{2x}\sin x
$$
and differentiate:
$$
F'(x)=2ae^{2x}\cos x-ae^{2x}\sin x+2be^{2x}\sin x+be^{2x}\cos x=
e^{2x}\bigl((2a+b)\cos x+(2b-a)\sin x\bigr)
$$
and we can set
$$
\begin{cases}
2a+b=1\\
a-2b=0
\end{cases}
$$
that gives $a=2/5$ and $b=1/5$.

Alternatively, recall that $\cos x=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$ so your integral becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int(e^{(2+i)x}+e^{(2-i)x})\,dx
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2+i}e^{(2+i)x}+\frac{1}{2-i}e^{(2-i)x}\right)+c\\
&=
\frac{e^{2x}}{10}\bigl((2-i)e^{ix}+(2+i)e^{-ix}\bigr)+c
\end{align}
and it's just a matter of computing the function in brackets:
\begin{align}
(2-i)(\cos x+i\sin x)+(2+i)(\cos x-i\sin x)
&=2\cos x+\sin x+2\cos x+\sin x\\
&=4\cos x+2\sin x
\end{align}